# Access mutable java.util.List in Clojure

Tags: java, list, clojure, mutable

I'm working with a 3rd party Java library, one of the library events passes a java.util.List as a parameter which Clojure exposes as a clojure.lang.APersistentVector.  The problem I'm having is that the library requires that I mutate that list to achieve the functionality I am after.  However, as Clojure has returned the list as APersistentVector all the mutable methods throw an UnsupportedOperationException.

Is it possible to force Clojure to work with a mutable Java implementation of List rather than the un-mutable Clojure version?

I appreciate that this is very un-Clojure like but its the way the Library works and for now, I just want to get things working.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear what you mean when you say "which Clojure exposes as a clojure.lang.APersistentVector".  If Clojure calls a Java method that returns an object x with class java.util.ArrayList, then calling `(class x)` in Clojure should show java.util.ArrayList.

Is there perhaps some conversion code happening in the library you are using, perhaps a Clojure wrapper for the Java method call(s), that is doing this conversion?

Example of Clojure REPL session showing you can indeed get java.util.ArrayList objects and mutate them in Clojure code:

```
user=> (def mutlist1 (java.util.ArrayList. [1 2 3]))
#'user/mutlist1
user=> mutlist1
[1 2 3]
user=> (class mutlist1)
java.util.ArrayList
;; add a new element -1 at index 1
user=> (.add mutlist1 1 -1)
nil
user=> mutlist1
[1 -1 2 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, what I am trying to implement is a function similar to this: https://github.com/ngs-doo/TemplaterExamples/blob/287d87dc2a8a2580ba6bdeb143d9f9dffbba86b0/Intermediate/LimitPlugins/src/main/java/hr/ngs/templater/example/LimitsExample.java#L22 I have used reify to extend the interface, the event is hooked up to a java.util.List (it doesn't get called if I use ArrayList).  However, the list class that is provided is clojure.lang.PersistentVector.  I've tried type hinting and that makes no difference,

Comment: Are you calling the API with a Clojure vector at some point, and then later the Java library is passing that back to you for modifications?  Because the Clojure persistent sequence data structures do implement the java.util.List interface (but not the mutation methods, which are optional according to Java API docs for that interface).

Comment: Yes, its configured by hooking up the java.util.List to the interface implementation (https://github.com/ngs-doo/TemplaterExamples/blob/287d87dc2a8a2580ba6bdeb143d9f9dffbba86b0/Intermediate/LimitPlugins/src/main/java/hr/ngs/templater/example/LimitsExample.java#L76).  It's then passed in a Clojure data structure and executed but when the function is called the list passed is persistent and errors when trying to mutate it.

Comment: Maybe I am thinking too simple-minded here, but if _your_ Clojure code is calling this object you created using reify, and your Clojure code is passing a Clojure vector to it, then of course that is not mutable.  You should change your code that calls that method to pass it a mutable implementation of the java.util.List interface, like a java.util.ArrayList.  If you have a Clojure vector v you can create such an ArrayList by calling (java.util.ArrayList. v).  If that is not what is happening, then I don't understand who is calling your reify object's method and passing it a Clojure vector

Comment: Thank you, the issue was my lack of understanding around Java interop.